# Poi 5.0 Jar movement Issue in XWPFDocument

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

I am currently Apache poi 3.14 version jar to create Word documents. I am now looking to upgrade Poi to latest stable version of 5.0. But upon checking I am facing issues where I am even unable to load document stream in XWPF document.  I have attached a sample code where I try to read a simple docx file & then re-write it again, I am getting error in place of even loading file bytes into XWPFDocument. I am baffled any detailed help would be really appreciated.

```
package basePackage;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;

public class PoiJars {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        String docxFilePath = "SimpleWordFile.docx";
        InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(docxFilePath);
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(stream);
                
        FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream("output.docx");
        document.write(outFile);
    }
}
```

Exception that occurs is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/chart/ChartSpaceDocument$Factory
    at org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.XDDFChart.<init>(XDDFChart.java:155)
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFChart.<init>(XWPFChart.java:75)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:61)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:660)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:165)
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.<init>(XWPFDocument.java:126)
    at basePackage.PoiJars.main(PoiJars.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.ChartSpaceDocument$Factory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 7 more
```

Jars I am using in Class path:

**poi-5.0.0.jar, poi-ooxml-5.0.0.jar, xmlbeans-4.0.0.jar** along with other commons & codec jar dependencies.

My queries are:

**1)Why I am not even able to load basic docx file in XWPFdocument?**

**2)If use poi-ooxml-full-5.0.0.jar instead of poi-ooxml-5.0.0.jar, XWPFDocument class is not present in it, what is reason ?**

**3)Also can some one pls help me in sharing some links to get complete understanding POI architecture & code flow, so I can modify classes in jar according to my needs.**

Comment: You need `poi-ooxml-5.0.0.jar` and **additional** either `poi-ooxml-lite-5.0.0.jar` or `poi-ooxml-full-5.0.0.jar`. See https://poi.apache.org/components/index.html. Your exception tells that it lacks either `poi-ooxml-lite-5.0.0.jar` or `poi-ooxml-full-5.0.0.jar`. And you should **not** have any `ooxml-schemas-*.jar` in classpath using `apache poi 5`.

Comment: Yeah thanks. It seems I was missing poi-ooxml-full-5.0.0.jar, adding this in class path solved my Issue 1. But still I am looking for an answer for queries 2 & 3 so that I could get an better understanding of POI working.

Comment: [Axel Richter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3915431/axel-richter?tab=topactivity) It will be really helpful If u could point me in direction of finding solutions for queries #2 & #3.

Comment: #2: You must not use `poi-ooxml-full-5.0.0.jar` **instead** of `poi-ooxml-5.0.0.jar`. You need both, `poi-ooxml-5.0.0.jar` **and** either  `poi-ooxml-lite-5.0.0.jar` or `poi-ooxml-full-5.0.0.jar`. `poi-ooxml-5.0.0.jar` contains the high level `apache poi` classes. `poi-ooxml-lite-5.0.0.jar` or `poi-ooxml-full-5.0.0.jar` contains the underlying XML schema classes. #3: See https://poi.apache.org/components/index.html.